# Can I downgrade my Minecraft Realm from 1.9 to 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Is there a way I can downgrade my Minecraft realm from 1.9 to 1.8? If so please tell me.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Realms can't have mods so I don't think of a reason.

Comment: I just want to play survival with my friends, we don't like 1.9.

Comment: why? Most game mechanics are the same (sure there is a cooldown etc, but they were in 1.8 too, just weren't as visible).

Comment: The 2 main reason are that we tend to drop lots of more often on 1.9 and the cooldown. We just prefer 1.8 a lot more

Comment: @ardaozkal I don't see how that is a valid question in a game whose official launcher allows you to play any version (including any bugfix release) since 1.0

Comment: @Deltharis not even 1.0, it supports all the alpha and betas! Still, I was asking why they want to do it, as there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is currently no way for Realms servers to be downgraded. To run a realm, the minecraft client must be up-to-date with the latest minecraft release, which means even if you got the actual realm server to 1.8, your 1.8 clients would tell you to upgrade to the latest client to even show the realms screen.